# Macro issue in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

Our customer just update macros then he found that all images is not appearing and system throw security issue.

Whould you help us solving this issue?

[image: Attached Image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+macro+signatures).

What you'll want to do is modify the web.config to include an appKey called `CMSHashStringSalt` with a GUID for a value.  Then go to the System>Macros>Signatures app and check both boxes and resign the macros which will use that new key in the web.config file.

If you have multiple environments, you'll want this key in all environments and you will have to resign your macros for each environment.  Also, note if you have a lot of data, resigning the macros can take a while so be patient even if it looks like the system has stalled out.

Answer (score -1):

What does it mean:

> customer just update macros

?

You could try to re-sign macro. You can find more info [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+macro+signatures). If it does not help post event log error.

Comment: I mean re-sign macro by update macros, resigned it with custom salt then the problem happened.

Comment: Did you try to re-sign macros with CMSHashSaltString vlaue?

Comment: no first we added random text then we resign again witn CMSHashSaltString value but still images don't come.

Comment: And what about log?